# XSLT for-each over 3 conditions out of 7

Tags: php, xml, xslt, soap, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to get cond1-3 in a for-each loop because the output tags are the same

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
 <stuff>
  <morestuff/>
 </stuff>
 <conds>
    <cond1>yes</cond1>
    <cond2>yes</cond2>
    <cond3>yes</cond3>
    <cond4>yes</cond4>
    <cond5>yes</cond5>
    <cond6>yes</cond6>
    <cond7>yes</cond7>
 </conds>
 <stuff>
  <morestuff/>
 </stuff>
```

so the output has to be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapheader/>
<soapbody>
 <somebiprostuff>
    <m:Element xsi:type="komp:CT_c">
    <v:Leistung>
        <v:ArtID xsi:type="dt:STE_d" />
        <v:Wert />
        <v:Werteinheit />
    </v:Leistung>
    <komp:ArtID xsi:type="dt:STE_something">666</komp:ArtID>
    <komp:Gefahr>
        <komp:Gefahr xsi:type="dt:STE_something">F</komp:Gefahr>
    </komp:Gefahr>
    <komp:Gefahr>
        <komp:Gefahr xsi:type="dt:STE_something">S</komp:Gefahr>
    </komp:Gefahr>
    <komp:Gefahr>
        <komp:Gefahr xsi:type="dt:STE_something">L</komp:Gefahr>
    </komp:Gefahr>
</m:Element>
<m:Element xsi:type="komp:CT_c">
    <v:Leistung>
        <v:ArtID xsi:type="dt:STE_d" />
        <v:Wert />
        <v:Werteinheit />
    </v:Leistung>
    <komp:ArtID xsi:type="dt:STE_something">777</komp:ArtID>
    <komp:Gefahr>
        <komp:Gefahr xsi:type="dt:STE_something">F</komp:Gefahr>
    </komp:Gefahr>
    <komp:Gefahr>
        <komp:Gefahr xsi:type="dt:STE_Gsomething">S</komp:Gefahr>
    </komp:Gefahr>
    <komp:Gefahr>
        <komp:Gefahr xsi:type="dt:STE_something">L</komp:Gefahr>
    </komp:Gefahr>
</m:Element>
 </somebiprostuff>
</soapbody>
```

so when the input xml contains the product for 666 and 777 and cond1-3 are yes this should be the right output.

I tried to deal with it this way but it didn't worked very well

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<soapheader/>
<soapbody>
<somebiprostuff>
<xsl:call-template name="element"/>
</somebiprostuff>
</soapbody>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:temaplate name="element">
<m:Element xsi:type="komp:CT_c">
<v:Leistung>
<v:ArtID xsi:type="dt:STE_d" />
<v:Wert />
<v:Werteinheit />
</v:Leistung>
<komp:ArtID xsi:type="dt:STE_something">777</komp:ArtID>
<xsl:for-each select="//cond1 = 'yes' or //cond2 = 'yes' or //cond3 = 'yes'">
<komp:Gefahr>
<komp:Gefahr xsi:type="dt:STE_xy">
<xsl:choose>
<!-- cond1 -->
<xsl:when test="//cond1 = 'yes'">
<xsl:value-of select="'F'"/>
</xsl:when>
<!-- cond2 -->
<xsl:when test="//cond2 = 'yes'">
<xsl:value-of select="'S'"/>
</xsl:when>
<!-- cond3 -->
<xsl:when test="//cond3 = 'yes'">
<xsl:value-of select="'L'"/>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</komp:Gefahr>
</komp:Gefahr>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:/template>
```

this results in an empty output.
how can i get this loop right, if there is the possibility to get 3, 2 or 1 repetition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules of the required transformation are not entirely clear. Would something like this work for you?

```
<xsl:template match="conds">
    <result>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="cond1 | cond2 | cond3"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cond1 | cond2 | cond3">
    <xsl:if test=".='yes'">
        <t:x>
            <t:x xsi:type="dt:STE_xy">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="self::cond1">F</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="self::cond2">S</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="self::cond3">L</xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </t:x>
        </t:x>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: following code should generate the right output, but doesn't looks nice:

`<xsl:if test="//cond1 = 'yes'">
  <t:x>
    <t:x xsi:type="dt:STE_xy">F</t:x>
  </t:x>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="//cond2 = 'yes'">
  <t:x>
    <t:x xsi:type="dt:STE_xy">S</t:x>
  </t:x>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="//cond3 = 'yes'">
  <t:x>
    <t:x xsi:type="dt:STE_xy">L</t:x>
  </t:x>
</xsl:if>`

Comment: @Mofty Doesn't my "nice" code generate the same output?

Comment: Didn't work that way for me so i wrote it in a separate template and called it

Comment: @Mofty I don't think that should be necessary - but you don't show us the entire picture.

Comment: Nice logic, plus one.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm not allowed to do so, but it helped me to get to an answer

Comment: I will update my code tomorrow so that the problem will be reproducible